# Nginx reverse proxy glassfish not serving resources properly

Tags: nginx, jsf-2, nginx-location, glassfish-4, nginx-reverse-proxy

im setting up a proxy on a java ee webapp deployed on a glassfish server and want it to be accessible by a subdomain on Nginx but, still have resources not served and while clicking on any `<h:commandLink />` or `<h:commandButton />` i get  `http://sub.domain.com/#` on the main page. I walked through other questions on the site and suggested to add a location section in the config like the snippet below but pages comes without resources. All the pages use a template located under `WEB-INF/template.xhtml`. I want to mention that accessing the app by just using `ip:8080/app` works as expected. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/app/;
        expires 30d;
    }
```

Im using JSF. Below are my configurations:

App config in Nginx

```
upstream sub.domain.com {
  server ip:8080 weight=100 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=5;
}

server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     sub.domain.com;

  location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://sub.domain.com/app/;


  }

location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/app/;
        expires 30d;
    }

}
```

Here is  my resources folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Check the order of the locations

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the debugger in the browser of your choice. Are the resources even being requested? If so, with what status code do they fail? Are there any exceptions or helpful logs in your application? I had a similar issue using apache2 where the Host and Referer request headers and the Location Response Header weren't properly rewritten.

Comment: The resources are not loading, their status code is 404. This is the same case with apache2